# Is it possible to have R write out .sbn and .sbx files?

Tags: shapefile, r, spatial-query

I'm working on an situation where a client wants, in addition to the .shp & .prj files that I can produce with e.g. `rgdal::writeOGR`, the .sbn & .sbx files as well.

My understanding is this is an ARCGIS proprietary file type (?), as explicated [here](http://gisgeography.com/arcgis-shapefile-files-types-extensions/), which is designed to facilitate lookups/queries on larger shapefiles (which indeed I am dealing with).

Is this truly a proprietary file type, or is there some way to produce these indices using R tools?

Comment: If your client opens the shapefiles you provide in Arc and then saves a copy, those extra files are created automatically. If there are many files to handle, they can use arcpy with 'Feature Class to Feature Class' to automate the process.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

From the GDAL docs, which is what R uses:

> Starting with OGR 1.10, it can also use the ESRI spatial index files
>   (.sbn / .sbx), but writing them is not supported currently.

So not possible. Someone has reverse-engineered the formats for reading them, but not implemented writing them yet.

GDAL uses a `.qix` file for spatial indexing, but I don't know if that's supported by ESRI.

Comment: .qix is **not** supported by ArcGIS.